# device not have a enough space

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory, google, huawei

I have a HUAWEI honor 3C.  I am downloading facebook Messanger but play store displayed device not have a sufficient memeory while 308MB internal memory is free.  I clean cache memory but didn't work. Please help me out.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to move some apps to the sdcard? I use `SDMove` with another Huawei model.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're too low on free disk space, not because you're completely out of it. Android will not let you install certain apps once you're using too much of your internal memory. Either get a MicroSD card and use an app like [AppMgr III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) to move a couple of apps to it, or the one the other person that commented mentioned, or uninstall a couple of apps to free up some space. AppMgr III is nice because even if you don't have a MicroSD card, you still should be able to use it to easily see which apps are taking up the most space and remove one or two that are preventing you from installing your messenger app. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving apps to sdcard, or external_sd.

Try using Link2SD app (root needed).

Try deleting useless apps.

Try clearing some space on sdcard too (not only in internal storage).